# unable setText() in JTextField from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two JFrames named first and second respectively. Both frames have jtextfields to getText() and setText(). I am able to setText from first to second JFrame, but unable setText from second to first.

In first and second frame I have made all JTextFields `public static`

first.java

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    second sec = new second();  
    sec.jTextField1.setText(this.jTextField1.getText()); // this works
    sec.jTextField2.setText(this.jTextField2.getText()); 
    sec.setVisible(true);

    public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
```

second.java

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   first f = new first();
   f.jTextField1.setText(this.jTextField3.getText()); //not working
   f.jTextField2.setText(this.jTextField4.getText());
   }
   public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
   public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
   public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
   public static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
   private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
```

on click of second frames button first frame should get updated. I don't want open first frame again.

Comment: But your both class name is name !! ?

Comment: are you using netbeans?

Comment: yes. and class names are `first` and `second`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "don't want open first frame again" then you must avoid creating a new instance of first and use a reference of your previous instance instead.

So you need a reference... one way to give your second a reference to first is provide it in the constructor, like:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
  second sec = new second(this);  //notice I'm passing a reference to this as an argument second's contstructor   
  sec.jTextField1.setText(this.jTextField1.getText()); // this works
  sec.jTextField2.setText(this.jTextField2.getText()); 
  sec.setVisible(true);
```

Then  you need to store the reference to first in your second class and use it to access textfields:

```
private first f;
public second(first referenceToFirst){
  this.f=referenceToFirst;
}
```

ok, then use f field instead of instantiating a new first when clicking the button on second...

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
  //first f = new first();  //don't instantiate a new first, use the one you got in the constructor
  f.jTextField1.setText(this.jTextField3.getText());
  f.jTextField2.setText(this.jTextField4.getText());
}
```

Notes:

I wouldn't make textfields public static, I'd rather provide getter methods.

I suggest you adhere to naming conventions: use capital letters for classes and use significant names for variables.

Comment: _"I wouldn't make textfields public static, I'd rather provide getter methods."_ **`public static` IS NOT the way!**

Answer (score 1):

Before I begin, have a look at [**The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

> "on click of second frames button first frame should get updated. I don't want open first frame again."

It's not working because you're creating a new `JFrame` (`first`). Of *course* it's going to  open a new frame. Instead of creating a new frame, pass the same one as a reference.

I'll give you an example using a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`. If after you read the above link and you still decide a `JFrame` is what you want, the same code can be implemented into a `JFrame`. They basicially have the same constructs.

So basically what I mean by passing a reference is this. Pass the `JFrame` to the constructor of the `JDialog`. This way the `JFrame` you pass to it, will be the same referenced `JFrame`.

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    private First frame;
    private JTextField thisTextField;

    public MyDilaog(final First frame, boolean modal) {
        super(frame, modal);
        this.frame = frame;

        thisTextFiled = new JTextField(20);
    }
}
```

Int your `First` class just create it like this

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(First.this, true);
```

Now you have a reference to the frame. You also want a `getter` in the `JFrame` class that will access the `JTextField` from the `JFrame` class. Then you can set its text, as it also is referenced. So you can do something like this from the `JDialog`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String text = thisTextField.getText();

    JTextField fieldFromFrame = frame.getTextField();
    fieldFromFrame.setText(text):
}
```

---

Also, you need to use Java naming convention. Class names being with capital letter. So `First` not `first`

Comment: what is `frame.getTextField();` which type of method is this.

Comment: If you read the complete answer, you would have noticed that I said to create that method in the JFrame class, that will return the text field you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

try to passe your second jframe as parameter in the first jframe than use it to change your textfield